# Data structure of 24 bit raw rgb-file

Tags: text, data-structures, rgb, data-conversion

In order to convert the current date from text to rgb, I'd need to know the exact structure of a file.rgb.

I know that every Pixel is coded with 3 bytes

```
RRGGBB.
```

Black would be

```
0x000000
```

and white

```
0xFFFFFF.
```

In all the internet I couldn't get one image.rgb. They all were png, bmp, jpg or jpeg files.

1. I'd need a file.rgb in order to understand its structure. Where can I get it? Does it have a header and how are the values of the pixels seperated? (e.g. space, comma…). And is there a special sign/value for    new line   ?
2. I'd like to know how many Pixels are used for an A4 page.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about file formats. Rather than trying to write the file, write a program that creates an image in memory (using whatever your development language/environment's defined image object is), and then call the image's method that writes it to file.

Comment: The number of pixels on an A4 page depends on how many pixels per inch. A 72 dpi image requires a lot fewer pixels than a 300 dpi image.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'd like to create it "by hand". I'm working with Python 3.6 and I need to create an image from a text. The files should be in .tiff .png and .jpeg format. I thought creating an rgb-"raw data" file  and then convert it into the other formats would be the best way.

Comment: I think you are missing one step. When reading a file, we put them in a buffer, which is usually RGB. Use standard way to read files, and so you will get a RGB buffer. often you can control how it is formatted (32bit, and order).